# nginx rewrite location to one served locally

Tags: nginx, single-page-application, nginx-location

I have two SPA-applications in two different languages.
`index.html` is the same, the only difference is in phrases built in js code. I use nginx to serve them basing on cookie

It may be served from folder as built and bundled app or from localhost(docker in my case, but I guess it doesn't matter)

When app is built and bundled, there is no problem – everything works with cookie or without.
But as soon I want to serve *english* version, rewriting to localhost port fails. It loads correct index.html, but all static files fail with 404.

How can I fix this?

*UPD*: it works fine with *redirect* instead of rewrite and different base-href. But it is not a nice solution(

My config looks like

```
 location ^~ /app {
            if ($http_cookie ~* "locale_en") {
                rewrite  ^(.*)/app(.*)$  $1/app-en$2 last;
            }
            alias /var/www/myproject/dist/apps/myapp;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string @app-site;
        }


        location ^~ /app-en {
            alias /var/www/myproject/dist/apps/myapp-en;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string @app-site-en;
        }


        location @app-site {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:42031;
        }

        location @app-site-en {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:42030;
        }
```

index.html of both apps looks like

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/app/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: static files also send cookies, so second location would apply internal alias for statics

Comment: it is ok, because static is stored on the same port locally

Comment: i have found that if i use `base-href` as app-en, it works ok, but cant figure why

Comment: you could trace your 404s with detailed `error_log`